# When Windows XP will run the updater?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-update, sp3

I have installed a VM with Windows XP Professional. Everything works right, I'm just waiting the system to automatically run the Windows Updater, to get the SP 3 and all that stuff. In the Control Panel the Windows Update option is enabled, to tell me when to install the updates and select which one too. The problem is that I installed WinXP about a week ago and the Windows Update icon is not here... I'm waiting and waiting. I tried running the Windows Update from the IE 8 (which I updated manually) but it always says that "an error ocurred".

Is there any other way to force Windows to download the updates?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should be able to run Windows Update yourself.  If you are unable to do so there is likely a system integrity problem.

Comment: That's the problem. I run Windows Update manually and IE is opened. From there I select the "Custom" installation option and then it crashes.

Comment: Why don't you just download Service Pack 3 through the browser, apply the update, alternative use an installation disk with it already installed.

Comment: Yes that's what I did and now it work's. I did that before you post your comment, but however, +1. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a WinXP box here, but I remember it having a `wuauctl` command to control the auto-update process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm writing that in the cmd and it says there's no such command...

Answer (score 0):

Finally the solution was to manually install the SP3 from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/es-ar/download/details.aspx?id=24). Now the Windows Update icon is there!